# No key available with this passphrase luks bash

Tags: bash, luks

I am trying to remote configure my host with a script.
However it fail when doing cryptsetup luksOpen

here is my function:

```
# used to encrypt the volume
# $1 the ssh connect
# $2 the partition
# $3 the password
# $4 the LUKSName
encrypt(){
ssh $1 << EOF
  sudo -s
  # convert the partition to the LUKS format
  echo "About to init luks on partition: cryptsetup luksFormat $2 with [YES, $3, $3]"
  (
  echo YES
  echo $3
  echo $3
  ) | cryptsetup -v luksFormat $2
  sleep 3
  echo "About to mount and format: cryptsetup luksOpen $2 $4 with [$3]"
  (
  echo $3
  ) | cryptsetup -v luksOpen $2 $4
  # Create an EXT4 file system on the LUKS logical volume
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/$4
  # optional create the luks.key
  echo $3 > /root/luks.key
  echo "About to create the luksKey: cryptsetup luksAddKey $2 /root/luks.key with [$3]"
  (
  echo $3
  ) | cryptsetup luksAddKey $2 /root/luks.key
  # enter the new volume in /etc/fstab
  echo "/dev/mapper/$4 /$4 ext4 defaults 1 2" >> /etc/fstab
  # create the mount point
  mkdir /$4
  #mount the luks volume
  mount /$4
EOF
}
```

So my logs are correct for the luksFormat but fail with luksOpen

```
About to init luks on partition: cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb1 with [YES, pwd, pwd]
Command successful.
About to mount and format: cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 mongo_data with [pwd]
No key available with this passphrase.
Command failed with code 1: No key available with this passphrase.
```

When I do it manually it is working.

Here is debug traces:

```
# cryptsetup 1.6.6 processing "cryptsetup --debug luksOpen /dev/sdb1 mongo_data"
# Running command open.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating crypt device /dev/sdb1 context.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb1.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load LUKS1 crypt type from device /dev/sdb1.
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.6.5) initialized.
# Detected kernel Linux 4.4.0-81-generic x86_64.
# Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device /dev/sdb1
# Key length 32, device size 20969472 sectors, header size 2050 sectors.
# Timeout set to 0 miliseconds.
# Password retry count set to 3.
# Password verification disabled.
# Iteration time set to 1000 miliseconds.
# Activating volume mongo_data [keyslot -1] using [none] passphrase.
# dm version   OF   [16384] (*1)
# dm versions   OF   [16384] (*1)
# Detected dm-crypt version 1.14.1, dm-ioctl version 4.34.0.
# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
# dm status mongo_data  OF   [16384] (*1)
# STDIN descriptor passphrase entry requested.
# Trying to open key slot 0 [ACTIVE_LAST].
# Reading key slot 0 area.
# Using userspace crypto wrapper to access keyslot area.
# Trying to open key slot 1 [INACTIVE].mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
# Trying to open key slot 2 [INACTIVE].The file /dev/mapper/mongo_data does not exist and no size was specified.
# Trying to open key slot 3 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 4 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 5 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 6 [INACTIVE].
# Trying to open key slot 7 [INACTIVE].
# STDIN descriptor passphrase entry requested.
# Nothing read on input.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sdb1 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Unlocking memory.
```

It seems that *Nothing read on input* means that it did not get my password...

Do you maybe have an idea?

Regards

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble by calling the tools non-interactively, such as with `cryptsetup luksFormat yourdevice --key-file fileThatContainsYourPassword`. Pretending to be a human is hard.

Comment: This is the best answer. Sorry to have to say it in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password for your encrypted container is `YES`... `cryptsetup luksFormat` does not carry out the dialogue when standard input is not a terminal; it just reads one line and uses that as the password.